# Method to fix the video-projector deformation with GLSL/HLSL full-screen shader

Tags: glsl, hlsl, fragment-shader, virtual-reality

I am working in VR field where good calibration of a projected screen is very important, and because of difficult-to-adjust ceiling mounts and other hardware specificities, I am looking for a fullscreen shader method to “correct” the shape of the screen.

Most of 2D or 3D engines allows to apply a full-screen effect or deformation by redrawing the rendering result on a quad that you can deform or render in a custom way.

The first idea was to use a vertex shader to offset the corners of this screen quad, so the image is deformed as a quadrilateral (like the hardware keystone on a projector), but it won’t be enough for the requirements 
(this approach is described on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript) with a live fiddle demo).

In my target case:

- The image deformation must be non-linear most of the time, so 9 or 16 control points are needed to get a finer adjust.
- The borders of the image are not straight (barrel or pillow effect), so even with few control points, the image must be distorted in a curved way in between. Otherwise the deformation would make visible linear seams between at each control points’ limits.
  Ideally, knowing the corrected position of each control points of 3x3 or 4x4 grid, the way would be to define a continuous transform for the texture coordinates of the image being drawn on the full screen 
  quad:

*u,v => corrected_u, corrected_v*

You can find an illustration [here](http://reviatech.com/content/correction.png).

- I’ve saw some FFD algorithm that works in 2D or 3D that would allow to deform “softly” an image or mesh as if it was made of rubber, but [the implementation seems heavy for a real-time shader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_deformation).
- I thought also of a weight-based deformation as we have in squeletal/soft-bodies animation, but seems uncertain to weight properly the control points.
  Do you know a method, algorithm or general approach that could help me solve the problem ?
- I saw some mesh-based deformation like the new Oculus Rift DK2 requires for its own deformations, but most of the 2D/3D engine use a single quad made of 4 vertices only in standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need non linear deformation [Bezier Surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface) are pretty handy and easy to implement.

You can either pre build them in CPU, or use hardware tessellation (example provided [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tessellation-70afba2c))

Comment: Thanks for your input. Indeed I used these equations to interpolate the offsets I was using. cosine interpolation was not what I needed in most cases. I used the quadratic factors from bezier (vec4((1.0-x)*(1.0-x), (x)*(1.0-x), (x*x), 1.0)) and multiply them with the key values corresponding to "0.0", "0.5" and "1.0" control values. Quite nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my research, I found a way.
I created a 1D RGB texture corresponding to a "ramp" or cosine values. This will be the 3 influence coefficients of offset parameters on a 0..1 axis, with 3 coefficients at 0, 0.5 and 1 :

- Red starts at 1 at x=0  and goes down to 0 at x=.5
- Green start at 0 at x=0, goes to 1 at x=0.5 and goes back to 0 at x=1
- Blue starts at 0 at x=0.1  and goes up to 1 at x=1

With these, from 9 float2 uniforms I can interpolate very softly my parameters over the image (with 3 lookups on horizontal, and a final one for vertical).

Then, one interpolated, I offsets the texture coord with these and it works :-D
This is more or less a weighted interpolation of the coordinates using texture lookups for speedup.